# What is the lower $n$ such that $\mathbb{HP}^2$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, mathematical-physics

Applying  basic cohomological calculus it is possible to  derive that $\mathbb{HP}^2$ cannot be embedded in a Euclidean space of dimension 11 or less.

From other side, applying spinorial cohomological calculus (Mayer integrality theorem), I am deriving  that $\mathbb{HP}^2$ cannot be embedded in a  Euclidean space of dimension 12.

Also it is well known that $\mathbb{HP}^2$ can be immersed into $\mathbb{R}^{15}$.

Then my question is:

What is the lower $n$ such that $\mathbb{HP}^2$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?